# Copying over taxonomy structure from one CPT to another

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I have a CPT called adverts and it has 2 taxonomies - category and location. The problem is that there are about 100 entries in location taxonomy and I need to copy the same structure to another CPT - businesses. Doing everything manually will take forever. Are there any solutions for that?

P.S. Taxonomy structure includes parent and children hierarchy
P.P.S. I checked the DB structure and due to its design it is hard to find all relations and taxonomies there as they are in various tables. Maybe there some kind of a plugin?

Comment: Do you want to copy 100 location terms from your original post/page type to the CPT type?

Comment: Nope, I have a CPT "adverts" that has taxonomy "location" consisting of 100 terms. And I need my CPT "businesses" to have the same taxonomy with the same terms

Comment: How are you registering the taxonomies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register the taxonomies you can specify multiple post types:

```
function register_my_taxonomies() {
register_taxonomy(
                  'location',
                  array('post','page', 'adverts', 'businesses'),
```

Comment: Heh, that was so easy. I had no idea that the post type can be in array when registering the taxonomy. Life saver!

Comment: My pleasure. Welcome to the site!